# database integration user signup w/php

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

Can someone post some code on just posting one line of data to the database and reading a line of data back to view in Xcode? I have a basic PHP file and Xcode project I have been playing with and it updates a row in my database but info is blank in both fields.

PHP code minus domain and hosting info:

```
<?php

$username = "Username";
$pass = "Password";
$database = "test";

mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $pass);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Unable to find database");

$name = @$_POST["name"];
$message = @$_POST["message"];

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('', '$name', '$message')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));

mysql_close();

?>
```

the .h file

`#import

```
         #define kPostURL @"http://localhost/TESTCONNECT.php" //variable to          use         whenever
#define kName @"name"
#define kMessage @"message"



@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextField *nameText;
IBOutlet UITextView *messageText;

NSURLConnection *postConnection;
}

-(IBAction)post:(id)sender;


@end
```

the .m file

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

}




-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) message withName:(NSString *) name{

if(name !=nil && message !=nil){

     NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString          stringWithString:kPostURL];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName, name]];

     [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];

    [postString setString:[postString         stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: postString]];


     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

     postConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


 }
 }

 -(IBAction)post:(id)sender{
 [self postMessage:messageText.text withName:nameText.text];
[messageText resignFirstResponder];
 messageText.text=nil;
 nameText.text=nil;}




  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 }


 @end
```

If someone has a better way to do this with Xcode 7.2 and swift 2 I would like to make the switch if I could.

Comment: Why does your title say "Swift 2" but your question contains a bunch of Objective-C code?

Comment: I cant find any code that works in swift 2 so I had go with obective c to see If I at least get that to work.

Comment: I think if I could just get the data there I can worry about validation and security later.